# Where can I find webmin for Ubuntu 10?

Tags: installation, downloads, webmin

I would like to install webmin, but it is neither available from Synaptic, nor from `apt-get`.

Why can't I find it in synaptic or apt-get? How can I get it and install?

Comment: Can you please let us know the exact version of Ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Webmin is not in any Ubuntu repositories. You will need to download the debian package file (.deb) at http://www.webmin.com/download.html

Their installation instructions for Debian apply to Ubuntu (and include Ubuntu specific notes) at http://www.webmin.com/deb.html